# How to Fill P5.js Shape with an Image

Tags: shapes, p5.js

I have created a shape using **beginShape**, **endShape** and **curveVertex**. My code looks like that:

```
function setup() {
 createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
 background(220);

 strokeWeight(5);
 point(84, 91);
 point(68, 19);
 point(21, 17);
 point(32, 91);
 strokeWeight(1);

 fill(0); // HOW TO FILL WITH IMAGE
 beginShape();
 curveVertex(84, 91);
 curveVertex(84, 91);
 curveVertex(68, 19);
 curveVertex(21, 17);
 curveVertex(32, 91);
 curveVertex(32, 91);
 endShape(CLOSE);
}
```

Instead of filling shape with a color, I want to fill it with an image. Is it possible with P5.js?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by using the [mask()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image/mask) function. In your case, create a graphics object and draw the shape you want and then use it as a mask for the image:

```js
let img
let shape 

function preload(){
 img = loadImage('https://picsum.photos/100')
}

function setup() {
 createCanvas(300, 100);
 
 // Create new p5 graphics object
 shape = createGraphics(100, 100);
 
 background(220);

 // Draw the shape
 shape.strokeWeight(5);
 shape.point(84, 91);
 shape.point(68, 19);
 shape.point(21, 17);
 shape.point(32, 91);
 shape.strokeWeight(1);

 shape.fill(0);
 shape.beginShape();
 shape.curveVertex(84, 91);
 shape.curveVertex(84, 91);
 shape.curveVertex(68, 19);
 shape.curveVertex(21, 17);
 shape.curveVertex(32, 91);
 shape.curveVertex(32, 91);
 shape.endShape(CLOSE);
 
 image(img, 0, 0)
 image(shape, 100, 0)
 
 // Use the shape as a mask
 img.mask(shape)
 
 image(img, 200, 0)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.min.js"></script>
```